# How do I shut down web services launched by Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with about 10 web services and one web site that calls them. All the services have to launch when I click "start debugging", which is necessary and good. When I stop debugging the services are still running. I can right click on each of them in the system tray to shut them down, or I can shut down Visual  Studio and they get shut down automatically. Is there a better way?

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409638/how-can-i-stop-visual-studio-running-all-my-web-services) which says how to not start the services in the first place, but I want the services to launch (and even want them to stay running more often than not.)

Answer (score 1):

[PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) includes pskill.exe which will kill all running processes with a given name.  If you're not concerned with closing the web services gracefully then this may be an option.

Comment: I guess that's better than nothing. I was hoping for some hidden command in visual studio or something.